# PowerShell Script launching a batch file on remote systems locally

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a simple batch file I need to run via PowerShell as a POC.  I need the batch file to run concurrently with the other batch files.

Batch file on each server at c:\pathtofile\file.bat:

```
cd /d c:\
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > null
ECHO test > c:\temp\echo.txt
time /t >> c:\temp\echo.txt
```

PowerShell script:

```
$servers = @(
    "Server02",
    "Server03",
    "Server04",
    "Server05",
    "Server06")
$creds = Get-Credential


foreach ($server in $servers){
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$Server" -Verbose -ScriptBlock {'cmd.exe c:\pathtofile\file.bat'} -Credential $creds
}
```

I've tried a million different things and I can't get the dang script to run.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `{'cmd.exe c:\pathtofile\file.bat'}` outputs the value of a verbatim _string literal_ (`'...'`). Just invoke a batch file as you would any other executable (prepend `& ` if the path is quoted and/or contains variable references): `{ c:\pathtofile\file.bat }`

Comment: On a separate note...you can pass the entire array to `Invoke-Command` and it will run the command in parallel.